# Is it correct to get a scholarship to do your final degree work?

Tags: funding, research-undergraduate

I applied for a public call for applications in which **scholarships** are awarded for the final year of my studies. The purpose of the fellowship is to promote the health sciences in other university studies.

Specifically, my studies are **computer science** and the project is to develop a web application to visualize medical images.

I have also discovered that the process of researching and learning new concepts motivates me. However, the aspect of having the **responsibility** of programming the application frustrates me, fills me with anxiety and causes discomfort, since I am actually a student who is finishing my degree studies, and it is the first time that I am doing an application for real use.

**In short**, I like the subject of using medical images, I hate programming the application because I get frustrated quickly, because I encounter difficulties with mathematical concepts, graphics or web programming that I have not been taught during my studies. Still, I do love the purpose for which the application is intended: to help the students and the veterinary teacher.

Considering I've already been paid my scholarship, is it correct that I've been given it?

EDIT:

There is a condition which states that tha maximum development time is a year since the scholarship's resolution which was on 10th november 2017.

Is it correct that they pay it before the app has been developed?

Comment: Hi, please edit your questions and clarify your circumstances. What do you mean by 'paid by scholarship, is it correct that I've been given it?'

Comment: You like the *concept* of research, but not doing the actual work? Hm. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If this is a final year project then the required output is as a learning exercise, which may not need the App to be completed and working.  But if this is a project for an external company then completion is probably the final objective.

If the scholarship was awarded to support the final year then yes, it is correct.

If the scholarship was awarded against the completion of the App, then you need to complete the App...

Does very much depend on the conditions of the scholarship though - which you need to check as necessary.